# Inequality proof in Tom Apostol's calculus book (Thm 1.15)

Tags: calculus, inequality, induction

I'm reading Tom Apostol's calculus and I'm a bit stuck on proving an inequality which is part of the proof of theorem 1.15 (the integral of $x^p$).

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^p < \frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}
$$

Now the author says this can be proven by induction, but I have been trying for a few days without success! I'm sure it's pretty straightforward but for some reason I cannot get to it.

I would really be grateful if someone could help me finding the way out of this!

Thanks
Fabrizio

Comment: It would be really great if you share your work and the manner you approached it!

Comment: $p$ is positive?

Comment: yes $p \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. In the inductive step you have to show that
$$\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}+n^p\leq \frac{(n+1)^{p+1}}{p+1}$$
that is
$$(p+1)n^p\leq (n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1},$$
or
$$\frac{p+1}{n}\leq \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{p+1}-1,$$
then use [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality).

Comment: Isn't the mean value theorem a lot to assume for someone studying introductory calculus?

Comment: Hi Robert, I think shredalert is right. At this stage I'm not supposed to know what MVT is. I got exactly at the point you said above, but I'm not sure how to show the inductive step! Thanks

Comment: Fine. You can use also Bernoulli's inequality. See my edited answer..

Comment: Excellent, thanks!