# How to use induction in an inequality proof for the integral of x^n

Tags: calculus, inequality, induction

I am working on the same problem as in this question: [Inequality proof in Tom Apostol's calculus book (Thm 1.15)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099995/inequality-proof-in-tom-apostols-calculus-book-thm-1-15/2100008#2100008)

But I am unable to understand how to get to the first step in the recommended answer.

Specifically, it suggests that in trying to prove this inequality:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^p < \frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1} \tag{1}
$$

We need to show:

$$
\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}+n^p\leq \frac{(n+1)^{p+1}}{p+1} \tag{2}
$$

Through further manipulations, we then arrive at a form that is equivalent to Bernoulli's inequality:

$$ (1+x)^k \gt 1 + kx \tag{3}$$ where $k = p+1$ and $x= \frac{1}{n} $

However, I am completely lost for how I can begin transforming the original inequality towards equation.  I've noted that the proof of Bernoulli's inequality itself uses induction for the variable p.  Therefore, my thinking is that there are exist either some theorems of which I am unaware that are useful in the beginning manipulations, OR the initial step is to begin with induction for the variable n. In trying the latter, I began by showing the base case n=1 is valid:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{0}k^p = 0 < \frac{1}{p+1} \tag{4}
$$

so in assuming the nth case, we try to show that the statement holds for n+1:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p < \frac{(n+1)^{p+1}}{p+1} \tag{5}
$$

From here, there needs to be some way of converting the summation into a form that uses an n or n+1 base, but I am stuck on this.  Online, I've found that [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) says:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p = \frac{1}{p+1}\sum_{k=0}^{p} \binom{p+1}{k} B_k n^{p-k+1}
$$

where $B_k$ are the Bernoulli numbers. However, these haven't been introduced in the book yet so I think there should be another way

Comment: Your equation $(5)$ can be written as $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^p+n^p<\frac{(n+1)^{p+1}}{p+1}$ and the first term of left side is less than $n^{p+1}/(p+1)$ (induction hypothesis). So if we can show that $n^{p+1}/(p+1) +n^p\leq (n+1) ^{p+1}/(p+1)$ (your equation $(2)$) then our job is done.

Comment: Also note that equation $(1)$ is your induction hypothesis which is assumed true. In short one needs to show that induction hypothesis $(1)$ implies $(5)$ and we use an independent inequality $(2)$ which is a consequence of Bernoulli inequality and combine it with $(1)$ to prove $(5)$ thereby completing the induction proof.

Comment: Thank you!  The step of splitting up the LHS after the first inductive step, and then substituting the original inequality for part of it was the insight I so dearly needed.  Very clever!